Java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo
I'm new to Detox and want to create a e2e Detox project for my own application(.apk).
I could successfully build and run the sample Detox project(as per official doc).
Made a necessary changes in the  ..detoxrc.js to run the custom .apk file.
'android.debug': {
type: 'android.apk',
binaryPath: '/Users/PatilJW1/Downloads/app-release.apk',
testBinaryPath: 'android/app/build/outputs/apk/androidTest/debug/app-debug-androidTest.apk',
build: 'cd android && ./gradlew assembleRelease assembleAndroidTest -DtestBuildType=debug',
reversePorts: [
8081
]
}

Error:

Java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: starting instrumentation ComponentInfo{test.mobile.test.ww.internal.test/androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner} from pid=9746, uid=9746 not allowed because package test.mobile.test.ww.internal.test does not have a signature matching the target test.mobile.test.ww.internal

